# Adding a table frame in ATLAS for QGIS

Tags: qgis, table, atlas, insert

I am customizing an ATLAS in QGIS and I would like to insert a table frame to introduce all attributes belonging to one feature. I have seen it is possible to add the attribute table but for my project, each sheet will be filled with the date from one feature (one row), I have noticed, I could perform this using just labels but I see this solution a bit tedious.

Does anyone know a better way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Add your attribute table to the layout and than check the box to include only the current atlas object:

[image]

As an alternative, you could add a text field. You than can introduce fields from the attribute table using the syntax `[% "name_of_your_field"  %]` or you can open the expression editor below and look for the fieldnames there or even format them. If you want, there is an option to style your textfield with html.

[image]

Comment: Exactly the second option is what i am looking for, but i also would like to give it a frame and customize a bit to make looks the PDF better. Do you know if this is possible? Thanks anyway as the answer helps me a lot.

Comment: You could style it using html. However, you also have plenty of options to style the attribute table inserted in the first option. In every case, it depends on what exactely you want to do, how the final output should look like.